# Black Screen, Blinking Cursor after cloning from HDD to SSD

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, boot-camp

(I'm aware there are similar questions, but from what I've seen I've already tried the fixes suggested.)

How I got into this situation:

- I'm running a Macbook Pro (Which means a hybrid GPT/MBR setup)
- I was running Windows dualbooted with Mac OSX on an HDD.
- I switched out for an SSD. Moved my Mac partition across fine.
- Used OSXs Bootcamp assistant create the partition for Windows to install too (So that OSX would handle correctly setting up the hybrid GPT/MBR).
- Used my Windows 7 Install Disk to format the new partition to NTFS.
- Cloned my old Windows 7 partition across, via OSX Disk Utility.

Problem: When trying to boot Windows 7 the boot routine hangs with the error-message-less blinking white cursor.

I have tried:

- Using OSXs Disk Utility on an install disk to repair the GPT/MBR setup of the disk.
- Startup Repair (It found some problems initially, but no longer finds any. No change in symptoms)
- chkdsk /F
- diskpart to mark the Windows 7 partition as active.
- bootrec /fixmbr
- bootrec /fixboot
- bootrec /rebuildbcd
- Exporting then removing the bcd, and rerunning bootrec /rebuildbcd

All the commands report success / no errors.

None of these have created any change in the symptoms.